# Проблема при замене текста при нажатии на кнопку,

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой, нажатие на кнопку затрагивает не только текст но и внутренние тэги. Подскажите как исправить.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="btn">Button</button>
<h1 id="home">
<img src="qwerty.png"/>
Old text
</h1>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {  
    document.getElementById("home").textContent = "Text for replacement";
};
```

И подскажите как сделать поиск по значениям атрибутов вместо `document.getElementById(id)`. Т.е.:

```
<div number="1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById("home").lastChild.nodeValue  = "Text for replacement";
            document.querySelector('[number="1"]').textContent = "Text for number = 1";
        };
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё работает! А можно записать параметры атрибута [number="1"] в отедельную переменную, чтобы менять цифру или название для разных объектов?

Comment: Да, конечно! `document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
            var n = 1;
            document.getElementById("home").lastChild.nodeValue  = "Text for replacement";
            document.querySelector("[number=\"" + n +"\"]").textContent = "Text for number = 1";
        };`